# bootstrap : insert dynamically a row in tab

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I try to insert this script inside a bootstrap tab .
My objective is to build a table dynamically.

My problem, every time I insert a new row my page is refreshed.

Do you have an idea to resolve this problem?

```
<table class="table table-sm table-hover" id="mtable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>Green</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Some Item</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table><br /><br />
<input id="row" placeholder="Enter Item Name" />
<button id="irow">Insert Row</button><br /><br />
<input id="col" placeholder="Enter Heading" />
<button id="icol">Insert Column</button>

<script>
      $('#irow').click(function(){
        if($('#row').val()){
          $('#mtable tbody').append($("#mtable tbody tr:last").clone());
          $('#mtable tbody tr:last :checkbox').attr('checked',false);
          $('#mtable tbody tr:last td:first').html($('#row').val());
        }else{alert('Enter Text');}
      });
      $('#icol').click(function(){
        if($('#col').val()){
          $('#mtable tr').append($("<td>"));
          $('#mtable thead tr>td:last').html($('#col').val());
          $('#mtable tbody tr').each(function(){$(this).children('td:last').append($('<input type="checkbox">'))});
        }else{alert('Enter Text');}
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is inside a form.

Change `<button>` to `<button type='button'>` to prevent it submitting form.

The default type for `<button>` is `submit` so the refresh would be due to form submitting.

If it isn't form related you will need to create a demo that reproduces the problem